# Date Time split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, split

I wanna calculate trimester from my date column, I already create semester and quarter using pandas
`df['quarter'] = df[label].dt.quarter`

`df['semester'] = np.where(df['quarter'].isin([1,2]), 1, 2)`
how could i do the same for df['Trimester'] ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFXU2.png)

and for my target value,it's the continuous value("Montant_engagé)

Comment: Kindly give an example of how is you dataframe structured and you expected output

Comment: thank u I made the changes

Comment: By Trimester - do you mean that jan-apr are trimester-1, May - Aug trimester2, and Sept-Dec Trimester3?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Also, it is not a good idea to insert images to display text. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Comment: @Roy2012  trimetre are 3 semester

Comment: I'd be glad to try to assist. Could you please add a data sample to the question, with a few rows as well as their expected output? I'm still not sure I understand what's the function you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
df['trimester'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month.isin([1,2,3,4]), 1, df['date'].dt.month)
df['trimester'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month.isin([5,6,7,8]), 2, df['trimester'])
df['trimester'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month.isin([9,10,11,12]), 3, df['trimester'])
```